# If $A$ is change-of-basis matrix from $B_1$ to $B$, show it's change-of-basis matrix from $B$ to $B_2$ for some $B_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Let $A$ be an invertible $n \times n$ matrix over an $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space. I was asked to show there are bases $B_1, B, B_2$ of $V$ such that $a.$ $A$ is a change-of-basis matrix from $B_1$ to $B$; $b.$ the same from $B$ to $B_2$.

Point $a$ is not too complicated. Simply let $\begin{pmatrix} \textbf{w}_1 & \ldots & \textbf{w}_n \end{pmatrix}$ denote the *columns* of $A$. Since $A$ is invertible these are linearly independent vectors and form a basis of $K$. Let $B = \{\textbf{w}_1, \ldots, \textbf{w}_n\}$ denote such basis, and set $ B_1 = \{\textbf{e}_1, ..., \textbf{e}_n\}$ arbitrarily to be the standard basis. Then $A$ is the change-of-basis matrix from $B_1$ to $B$.

So far so good. But point $b$ seems less trivial, at least to me. I've been struggling for hours trying to show some $B_2$ exists satisfying that $A$ is the change-of-basis matrix $B \to B_2$, with little success. I can reduce my attempts into two subgroups:

$I$. Firstly, I attempted to show this by contradiction. Assume there is no basis $B_2$ such that $A$ is the change-of-basis matrix from $B$ to $B_2$. Because $A$ does not map coordinates $(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)_B$ to corresponding coordinates $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)_{B_2}$ for any $B_2$ distinct from $B, B_1$, then only one of the following can be true:

$$\begin{align} A\textbf{x}_B &= \textbf{y}_{B}\end{align} \\ A\textbf{x}_{B} = \textbf{y}_{B_1}$$

In other words, either $A$ maps coordinates in $B$ to equivalent coordinates in $B$, or maps coordinates in $B$ to equivalent coordinates in $B_1$.

It is hard to deduce a contradiction from here. The first case is true if and only if $A = I$, which might very well be the case since $I$ is invertible. The same applies to the second case: it requires $A = A^{-1}$ (we are requiring $A$ to be change-of-basis $B \to B_1$ and we know it is change-of-basis $B_1 \to B$). We have no reason to assert $A$ is $I$ or $A^{-1}$, but we have no reason to assert *it is not* either.

This approach, by *reductio ad absurdum*, feels pretty close --as if  I am missing something vital to conclude it.

$II$. The second approach was more algebraical. For any $\textbf{x}_B$ we have

$$\begin{align} A\textbf{x}_B &=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} x_1 + \dots + a_{1n}x_n \\ \dots \\ a_{n1}x_1 + \ldots + a_{nn}x_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}z_1 \\ \vdots \\ z_n \end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$

So for A to be the change-of-basis matrix $B \to B_2$ we require

$$\begin{align} \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} x_1 + \dots + a_{n1x_n} \\ \dots \\ a_{n1}x_1 + \ldots + a_{nn}x_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix}\end{align}_{B_2}$$

for some basis $B_2$. So one should set out to show this system has at least a solution. And one must keep in mind each column of $A$ is defined to be a vector in $B$. I found this approach too desperate and cumbersome, and it lead me nowhere.

How am I supposed to solve point $b$ of this problem?

Comment: Apply point a to $A^{-1}.$

Comment: Your comment helped me a lot, thanks @AnneBauval!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general,  an invertible matrix $A$ can be interpreted as the change of basis from the basis $B_1$ consisting of its columns to the standard basis $B$; or, if we switch viewpoint, from the standard basis $B$ to the basis $B_2$ such that $B$ expressed in terms of $B_2$  is $B_1.$

That's $B_2=\{A^{-1}e_1,\dots, A^{-1}e_n\},$ the columns of $A^{-1}.$

Answer (score 0):

Let  $V$ be the vector space and let $\{v_1....,v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$. A member $v$ of $V$ can be written as $c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n $and hence as a column vector $\text {vec}(v_n)$ whose $i-$th component is $c_i.$ Thus any basis  $W=\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ of $V$corresponds to an $n \times n$ matrix mat$(W)$ whose $j-$th column is vec$(w_j)$. The correspondance is 1-1. Then $A\text{mat}(B_1)=\text{mat}(B)$Thus $$A\text{mat}(B)=A^2\text{mat}(B_1).$$ Let $B_2$ be the basis of $V$ corresponding to the matrix $A^2\text{mat}(B_1).$ Then $A$ is the change 0f basis matrix from $B$ to $B_2$.